# SOAP WS-Security TimeStamp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, security

I need to implement SOAP WS-Security using TimeStamp.

Soap header should have Timestamp and expiration time and message should expire if it exceeds Expiration time.

I went through MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8728chd5%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77hkfhh8%28VS.71%29.aspx). These links discuss about specifying custom properties (Created & Expires) added to header and initialized before sending any request either way. But, I couldn't find any way to process that timestamp and invalidate the message.

Is the way specified in links is correct way of implementing Message expiration security ?
How can I process the information to validate the message ?

Comment: Well, if you migrate to WCF, WS-Security is already implemented and supported there - no need to for you to reinvent the wheel.....

Comment: WCF is not an option for me, more of a business decision (migration cost, time, risk, etc etc). How about WSE 3.0? I can have that worked out. But is there any good documentation available for implementing this through WSE?

Comment: WSE is obsolete. It is not supported in Visual Studio 2008 or above. It's a serious mistake to _begin_ using obsolete software when you don't have to. And, how much of a risk is it to use WCF, which has been out for three years?